# how to remove dash(-) in string using c#?

Tags: c#

```
   Regex rgx2 = new Regex("[^[0-9] . \n\r\t]");

   string  dash = Regex.Replace(Des_AccNo.ToString(), @" ^-");
```

- I need to clean this string **100-0@/2^2341?!** as **100022341**

Comment: Your code looks a but messy

Comment: Cannot see anything... But probably String.Replace("-", String.Empty);

Comment: You're not explaining what the issue is with your current code...

Comment: Tell us what you want to do. Show sample input and desired output.

Comment: Please post some relevant details as your input string, expected output etc....

Comment: Warning: your sample and your title doesn't match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to remove all non-numeric characters:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"[^0-9]", "");
```

Basically what that says is "if the character isn't a digit, then replace it with the empty string." The `^` as the first character in the character group negates it. That is, `[0-9]` matches any digit. `[^0-9]` matches everything *except* a digit. See [Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) in the MSDN documentation.

The expression `@"[^\d]"` also would work

Comment: is it two steps to remove dashes then to pack the area code  and number together without any spaces or is there a "one-shot" method?

Comment: @mLstudent33 It's a single step. This removes the dashes. So 999-555-1112 becomes 9995551212.

Answer (score 24):

I don't know what is your code, but you can do that by:

```
val = val.Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would basically create a static class that automatically pops up against any string.
If the same is GUID, you can simply do

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") returns only characters
```

Input: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc
Output: 12345678123412341234123456789abc

```
    public static string ToNonDashed(this string input)
    {
        return input?.Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 Des_AccNo = Des_AccNo.Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string dash = Des_AccNo.ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Please explain your code, rather than just giving code to solve the problem.

Comment: Please refer the following link for detailed explaination
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx